# Alterar a propriedade CSS Display para TODOS os elementos de uma página e deixar Block apenas para alguns?

Tags: css3, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando fazer a impressão de uma `bootstrap-modal` que é chamada dentro de um Form com `include`porém quero imprimir SOMENTE a modal, tem como fazer isso usando somente CSS? Vejam:

**Modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-protocolo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
CONTEUDO DA MODAL...
</div>
```

**Arquivo CSS:**

```
@media print {
*{
 display:none;
}
/* MODAL PROTOCOLO */
#modal-protocolo{
 display: block;
}
}
```

> O que posso usar aqui para selecionar todos os elementos da página?

```
*{
 display:none;
}
```

> Do jeito que está na hora da impressão fica tudo branco...

Comment: Seu problema é que quando vc da display:none no pai vc obrigatoriamente tb está dando display:none no filho, não há como vc dar display:none no pai e manter o filho com block, pois tudo dentro do pai tb vai estar como none.... E mesmo colocando `*:not(#modal-protocolo)` {display:none} não vai adiantar

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento meu amigo, consegui resolver utilizando um plugin Jquery, com CSS puro tava dando muito trabalho... Vou colocar a resposta

Comment: Gabriel eu consegui uma solução pra vc só com CSS caso interesse...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o seletor `*` seleciona **TODOS** os elementos do HTML (DOM), inclusive as tags `HTML` e `BODY`. Portanto se você oculta, por exemplo, o `BODY` com `display: none`, qualquer tag dentro do `BODY` estará oculto.

Para atingir esse resultado que você quer, a estrutura deve seguir o exemplo:

```css
body > * {
  display:none;
}
/* MODAL PROTOCOLO */
#modal-protocolo{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Teste</title>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Título de exemplo</h1>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <p>Conteúdo de exemplo</p>
  </main>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-protocolo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
  CONTEUDO DA MODAL...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sua solução funciona com alguns ajustes, contudo ainda fico com o Jquery, vou aceitar sua resposta, pois o que eu queria era uma solução apenas com CSS,  abraços meu amigo...

Answer (score 2):

Tenho uma solução para vc apenas com CSS. É um tipo de *hake*, mas basta vc colocar um `box-shadow` gigante no seu modal na hora da impressão, dessa forma ele vai tampar tudo que estiver por traz, dando a impressão que só tem o modal na página.

Conforme dito no comentário o problema do `*{ display:none; }` é que quando vc da `display:none` no pai vc obrigatoriamente tb está dando `display:none` no filho, não há como vc dar `display:none` no pai e manter o filho com `block`, pois tudo dentro do pai tb vai estar como `none`.... E mesmo colocando `:not(#modal-protocolo) {display:none}` não vai adiantar...

Segue o código caso queira usa-lo:

Para testar clique em `Executar` como *"Página toda"* e depois de `Ctrl+P` e vc vai ver que os formes não aparecem na página, apenas o `modal`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <title>Page Title</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>

@media print {
 .modal.fade.show {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3000px #fff;
  position: fixed;
 }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 
 <div class="container m-5">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
    <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="container m-5">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-12">
    <form>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
      <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
     </div>
     <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
     </div>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
  ...
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Uma imagem com o resultado na hora do print.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Uma boa forma de resolver, contudo o meu DOM é muito grande, a modal iria ficar centralizada na página e com conteúdo pequeno... já tentei fazer algo parecido. Mesmo assim, obrigado.

Comment: @GabrielCarneiro sim, eu imaginei que para telas com muito conteúdo e um longo scroll esse problema poderia acontecer. Mas deixa a dica ai como registro, as vezes serve para quem está com problema similar, porem em uma situação diferente. Tmj

Comment: Valeu, abraços meu velho

Answer (score 1):

Bom, não consegui resolver utilizando somente CSS, parti pro uso de um Plugin Jquery chamado printThis, que é fácil de usar e não me deu tanto problema, seguem mais informações...:

```
$('#imprime-protocolo').click(function(){
    $(".imprimivel").html($("#modal-protocolo").html());
    $(".imprimivel #imprime-protocolo").remove();
    $(".imprimivel .fecha-modal-protocolo").remove();
    $(".imprimivel").printThis();
});
```

Plugin Disponível em: https://github.com/jasonday/printThis

**Inseri uma Div vazia logo após o main:**

```
</main>
<div class="imprimivel">

</div>
```

**E configurei o CSS assim:**

```
.imprimivel {
    display: none;
}
/* print styles*/
@media print {
    .imprimivel {
        display: block;
    }
}
```